# Smartschool API fetch students

Tags: php, soap

This is a very specific question to an online school platform.

I'm trying to use their API to get a list of all students (to start). But I can't even get that running.

In their manual are (only 2!) examples, but they are kind of complicated.

This is what I have, but I only get "19" printed out.

```
<?php
class SmartschoolConnection implements SmartSOAP {

    // URL opbouwen vanuit constante
    function getURL() {
        return "https://myplatform.smartschool.be/Webservices/V3?wsdl";
    }

    // Alle accounts ophalen
    function getAllAccountsExtended($sGroup) {
        try {
            $client = @new SoapClient($this->getURL());
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            return $e->faultstring();
        }

        $encoded = $client->__soapCall("getAllAccountsExtended", array("MyWebservicesPassword",$sGroup,'1'));
        $decoded = json_decode($encoded, TRUE);

        return $decoded;
    }
}

$smartschool = new SmartschoolConnection;

$pupils = $smartschool->getAllAccountsExtended("Klassen");

print_r($pupils);
?>
```

Comment: Is the `19` coming from `faultstring` or from the `json_decode`?

Comment: From the json_decode

Comment: Are you _sure_ about that? What's the output of `var_dump($encoded);`?

Comment: I tested it with `return $decoded."test";` `var_dump($encoded)` gives `int(19)`

Comment: Your code seems to work fine then, but the service isn't returning what you think it should, at which point you should be asking them.

Comment: Strange. I got the code from another Smartschool user and it seems to work fine for him. Every method I use gives 19 or a blank page... Thanks for the debugging help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seemed I didn't set the unique field in Smartschool for each group. 
That's why it give the error 19, wich seems to be *"Parent-id doesn not exist"*. Though I can't find those error codes in the manual...

Answer (score 0):

In their manual they have a function called 'returnErrorCodes'. That will give you a list (csv or json) with all their errorcodes and what they mean.

Comment: Is there a way for this to be in English? I used it and it returns json in Dutch and I can't find possibility to set another language.